# How to mock MD5 hash collision

Tags: python, md5, hashlib

I am using a private Ubuntu server and am testing a private application

I am using the Python `hashlib` library for generating MD5 hashes.

Now I want the MD5 function always return my specific number although different input. How can I do this? Is there a config file?

Comment: What is your use case?  Why would you **need** to do this?

Comment: This is an [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). Tell us what you really want to do.

Comment: I want to test my application using MD5. it is openstack swift. i have testing case about MD5 birthday. therefore i want to Md5 always has same output to examine my application that how it will handle that .

Comment: @NguyenDiep If it is in swift, then why do you mention Python in your post an why is it tagged python?

Comment: @techydesigner because i see MD5 written by python and swift also. if not, please ignore it.

Answer (score 4):

**DISCLAIMER**

As mentioned in the comments this is most likely a **TERRIBLE** idea and is very likely an [X / Y problem](http://xyproblem.info/).

---

For the sake of clarity, this is what I was referring to when I said it could be done via a monkey patch:

```
import hashlib

class DummyMD5():

    def __init__(self, realmd5):
        self.md5 = realmd5
        self.v = None

    def hexdigest(self):
        return "12345abcdef"

    def __call__(self, v):
        self.v = v
        return self

    def __getattr__(self, f):
        if f not in self.__dict__:
            return self.md5(self.v).__getattribute__(f)




_md5 = hashlib.md5
hashlib.md5 = DummyMD5(_md5)
```

As long as this is imported / executed before the hashlib call is used elsewhere it will replace the result of a `hexdigest` with a constant value.  Any other method would return the real md5 (like `digest`).

Comment: how to use your DummyMD5? my application configuration is: from haslib import md5. then use MD5(path) to return output.

Comment: This continues to be a terrible idea.  Tell us what you really want to accomplish instead.

Comment: @tripleee, my application use MD5 to hash path of object. i want to test in case if MD5 return same hash, what will happen. so that i want to change MD5 function to return same hash.

Comment: Congratulations, you have invented [mocking](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html). Unfortunately, this comment box is too small for a detailed tutorial.

Answer (score -1):

**tl;dr**
You can't, unless you write your own function or implement a monkey patch.

Hashes are not designed to return the same value for multiple completely different snippets of data (although inevitably there have been collisions, [like with MD5](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/1434/are-there-two-known-strings-which-have-the-same-md5-hash-value), due to the length of the hash). You could write your own function to check the value passed, and have it return a unique value if you need to. An example:

```
import hashlib

def my_func(thing):
    hash_for_cheese = 'fea0f1f6fede90bd0a925b4194deac11'
    if thing == "cheese":
        return hash_for_cheese
    elif thing == "football":
        return hash_for_cheese
    else:
        return hashlib.md5(thing).hexdigest()
```

In this case, the same hash would be returned if you passed `cheese` or `football` to the function, otherwise it would return another hash.

Also, there is no 'config file'. It is just a specific algorithm written in a C program. If you are desperate, you *might* be able to change it, but it would only work on your system.

You could also implement what is known as a monkey patch. I'm not knowledgeable in that area, but you can find out more information from [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5626193/what-is-a-monkey-patch).

As others have pointed out, I can not think of a use case for this sort of problem, although if you need to do it, then you have your answer.

Comment: Not the downvoter, but sure you can.  You can monkey patch if you really wanted to.  This is a terrible idea, but it is very possible.

Comment: What I meant when I said it was a bad idea was not specific to a monkey patching approach but to the general idea of returning a constant value for an md5 hash.  I would be very surprised if there is a valid use case for such a thing.

Comment: This is not true: "Hashes are not designed to return the same value *ever*", cryptographic hash functions are designed to make it *hard* to compute the same hash